# 802.11ac, stuck at 355KibiBytes/sec - weirdly common number?

Tags: wireless-networking, windows-8.1, wireless-router, 802.11ac

I have an ASUS RT-AC66U router (802.11ac - 2.4GHz and 5GHz) and an ASUS USB-AC56 802.11ac Wireless USB Adapter.

The router firmware is updated, all the QoS nonsense is disabled, and I'm using DHCP with manual MAC-IP assignments for devices on the network.

The main symptom: I get 75-80Mbit/s down over the net, and 145-180Mbit/s down from my ReadyNAS.  But **upload is weirdly capping out at ~2.91Mbit/s to both/either**.  I.e. I can upload to the NAS at 2.90816Mbit/s (355KibiByte/s exactly in Windows), or the internet, or with both combined they each average half that.

Signal strength is good and seems rock-solid.  Windows 8.1 reports a 390Mbit/s connection and full strength.

I'm at a complete loss as to what to try next to diagnose this problem.  Occasionally - very occasionally, and just for a few seconds, I've seen uploads at 20-30Mbps, again maxed out weirdly and in an unresponsive way.  But then it's back to ~2.91Mbps.

The thing is, Googling 355KibiByte/sec gives loads of results from similar people - saying various uploads to OneDrive and other seemingly unrelated situations (http://forums.dlink.com/index.php?topic=55196.0, http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/forum/sdperformance-sdimpperf/onedrive-file-downloads-appear-to-be-throttled-at/064407a4-6cd8-4e69-86f8-71b862922e1f).

Any tips of next steps I can try would be very welcome.  I'm a developer by trade so not afraid of in-depth tools or processes... What is the significance of 355KibiBytes/sec?  What can I do?

---

*Edit: I've used inSSIDer to check there's nothing else nearby, channel-wise.  I'm using 80MHz channel bandwidth.  I installed gcc, manually built iperf on the NAS box directly.*

*NAS-to-PC:*

*[  4]   0.00-1.01   sec  15.7 MiBytes   131 Mbits/sec*

*PC-to-NAS:*

*[  4]   0.00-10.01  sec  2.87 MiBytes  2.41 Mbits/sec*

---

New edit: just tried iperf (in fact iperf3) to check with my MacBook Pro - more than 220 Mbps both ways.  I've had different USB dongles on the PC - it's got to be a Windows issue.  Any ideas still very welcome :'(

Comment: try enabling QoS, especially WMM.

Comment: @Tetsujin - thanks for the suggestion.  I can't see any WMM option, but enabled QoS, with no effect.  Following http://superuser.com/questions/705608/802-11ac-poor-performance I changed the channel to something nothing else is using, which also made no difference. :/

Comment: ah, ok, sorry - it was just something that helped here, when I had a performance drop; I'd assumed killing QoS would speed things up, but it was actually the reverse.

Comment: @Spiff wonder if you can advise at all please?

Comment: Can you edit your Question to normalize your numbers to 1,000's and 1,000,000's of individual bits per second (network style throughputs)? Disk/File throughput usually uses 1,024's and 1,048,576's of 8-bit Bytes per second, and mixing both kinds of numbers in one post is kind of crazy-inducing.

Comment: @Spiff - thank you, I have tried.. the 355KB/sec is 2.91Mbps, I believe everything else is network-friendly Mbps.  If something is still not in alignment, do point it out please and I'll correct!

Comment: Thanks Kieren, I re-edited your edit to make the units very explicit. Please double-check that I didn't misinterpret something.

Comment: I see thanks, Kibi/Mi to be specific :)  The last part was a straight copy-paste from iperf, but I see your point! (No that's all good tyvm)

Comment: By the way, I updated that other 802.11ac slow speed answer you referenced to make clear that keeping WMM (wireless QoS) enabled, and either WPA2 (AES-CCMP) or no wireless encryption, is required for 802.11ac and 802.11n. But you're seeing better than a/b/g rates in most cases, so that probably isn't your problem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21716/discussion-between-spiff-and-kieren-johnstone).